# Mediawiki pages display incorrect

Tags: mediawiki

Sorry if there is an obvious answer for this, but I cannot find it.

I am using mediawiki 1.23.6-1 on Fedora 20

A while ago, the mediawiki part of each page changed dramatically,  looks like underlying code.

For example, at the top of the page the login link displays as

```
&lt;pt-login&gt;
```

This is true of all the mediawiki links on every page.

Although the user content is fine, the edit link on each section displays as

```
<editsection>
```

I can't find any errors anywhere and the wiki works fine except for this.

My guess is this started after a "yum update" command but I am not sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your wiki public? Can you give us the link?

Comment: No, unfortunately the wiki is private and running on an internal server.  I can probably post anything you would like to see though.

Comment: What happens if you append `?uselang=en`, `?uselang=ar` or similar to the url?

Comment: I tried a number of languages including en and ar but nothing changes.

Comment: So i18n is obviously broken. If you turn on [error logging](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug), do you see anything in your  logs?

Comment: found this in httpd/error_log, just once, looks like right after httpd started: `[Mon Dec 15 15:12:35.213839 2014] [:error] [pid 2985] [client ::1:48803] PHP Warning:  array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /usr/share/mediawiki/includes/cache/LocalisationCache.php on line 936`
`[Mon Dec 15 15:12:35.246538 2014] [:error] [pid 2985] [client ::1:48803] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/mediawiki/includes/cache/LocalisationCache.php on line 962`

Comment: Ok, so that probably means that you have earlier set up a localization cache, that now stopped working. I suggest you turn it off again (`$wgCacheDirectory=false;` in `LocalSettings.php`) to confirm that that is in fact the problem, and then start investigating. Make sure that the web server does have rw rights to you cache directory, etc.

Comment: I disabled the localization cache and the errors I saw stopped but I still have the same problem.  I noted that the "upload images" link is not there (its enabled in LocatSettings), also when I look at the pics I see "<thumbnail_error>" but I can see the full pic if I click on the link at the bottom of the page.  As a test, I also created a Fedora 21 VM with the current Mediawiki, restored the wiki filesystem and mysql database from backups and still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find the root cause of this issue.

As a workaround:

1 - I restored the wiki from backup to another system. 
2 - I deleted and recreated the *bad* wiki 
3 - I copied the user content from the old to the new and reuploaded the images

The wiki is running fine now.